# Richardson's Pamela: Letters addressed only to her mother

Tags: pamela, samuel-richardson

I'm trying to write a critical commentary for the passage near the beginning of *Pamela* ([letter XV](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/6124/6124-h/6124-h.htm#link2H_4_0017)) where she has her first 'Fit'. I've been trying to search for secondary criticism that discusses the instances where Pamela addresses letters only to her mother. Is there a reason she does this? It is her father who responds to the letters, so why would she set out to write just to her mother on certain occasions. I can't seem to find a pattern, can anyone else?